# Prove epsilon delta continuity for 4 real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove continuity at $(a,b)$
for the function $f:\Bbb R^2→\Bbb R,$ where $d((a,b),(c,d))=\left|a-c\right|+2\left|b−d\right|$
is my metric and my function is $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2.$

Show that one can make a suitable choice of $\delta>0$ which is a function of $\epsilon$, $a$ and $b$ such that for a given $\epsilon>0$: $$\left|a-c\right|+2\left|b−d\right|<\delta$$
implies that
$$\left|a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2\right|<\epsilon.$$

I attempted to use the triangle inequality on the above inequality to achieve:

$$\left|a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2\right|
\le\left|a^2-c^2\right|+\left|b^2-d^2\right|$$
$$=\left|(a-c)(a+c)\right|+\left|(b-d)(b+d)\right|$$

but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ fixed?

Comment: If all of $a,b,c,d$ are free to be any real numbers, then this claim is false. In particular, the case $b = d = 0$ is equivalent to the uniform continuity of $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbb R$, which does not hold. Namely, if one further takes $a = c+\delta$, then $|a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2| = (2c+\delta)\delta$. No matter how small one makes $\delta$, $c$ may be taken large enough such that this is larger than any fixed $\epsilon$.

Comment: Should it be: "For all $\epsilon$ one can make a suitable choice of $\delta$" ? (The way it's phrased now, I would say that the same $\delta$ should work for all $\epsilon$; but actually (I imagine) $\delta$ can depend on $\epsilon$.) Also, shouldn't $\epsilon$ be constrained to be positive?

Comment: @paw88789 thanks, yes ive edited it

Comment: @jawheele $\delta$ is a function of epsilon, a,b,c,d. I am trying to prove continuity at $(a,b)$ for a function that maps $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, where $d((a,b),(c,d))=∣a−c∣+2∣b−d∣$ is my metric and my function is $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval yes a and b are fixed, because I am trying to prove continuity at a point (a,b). See above comment.

Comment: @zakzaki Based on your description of trying to prove continuity under your metric, $\delta$ may depend on $\epsilon$, $a$, and $b$, but not on $c$ and $d$. You should add this information to the question, as necessary information shouldn't be hidden in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you'd like to demonstrate the pointwise continuity of $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ under the metric $d((x,y),(z,w)) = |x-z|+2|y-w|$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To prove continuity at a given $(a,b)$, then, for each $\epsilon > 0$ we must identify a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$d((x,y),(a,b)) < \delta \implies |f(x,y)-f(a,b)| < \epsilon.$$

Suppose that $d((x,y),(a,b)) < \delta$. In particular, this separately implies that $|x-a| < \delta$ and $|y-b| < \delta$. You've noticed that the triangle inequality yields the first of the following inequalities, which we continue:

\begin{align}
|f(x,y) - f(a,b)| & \leq |x-a||x+a| + |y-b||y+b| 
\\ & < (|x+a| + |y+b|) \delta
\\ & \leq (|x|+|a| + |y|+|b|) \delta
\end{align}

To complete the argument, we use that $|x-a| < \delta$ implies that $|x| \leq |a| + \delta$ (and similarly for $y$), meaning

$$ |f(x,y) - f(a,b)| <  2(|a| + |b| + \delta) \delta$$

From this, we see that choosing $\delta = \min \left( |a|+|b|, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|+|b|)} \right)$ yields the desired inequality (check this) so long as $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$. To establish continuity at the origin, we may simply take $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon/2}$.

Comment: Just a minor thing: the delta you wrote works at all points, except the origin $(a,b)=(0,0)$. In this last case, you can of course set $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Of course-- thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Letting $h:=b-a$ and $k:=d-c,$ your problem becomes:
given $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $\epsilon>0,$ find $\delta>0$ such that for all $h,k\in\Bbb R^2:$

$$|h|+2|k|<\delta\implies|h||2a+h|+|k||2b+k|<\epsilon.$$
Now, let$$M:=\max(|2a|,|b|).$$Then,
$$|h|+2|k|<\delta\implies|2a||h|+|2b||k|+h^2+k^2<M\delta+\delta^2.$$
It is therefore sufficient to choose $\delta>0$ such that
$$\delta^2+M\delta-\epsilon<0,$$
i.e.
$$\delta\le\frac{\sqrt{M^2+4\epsilon}-M}2.$$